# Subsets and Relations

Tags: relations, inverse

Prove the following:

Let f: X->Y be a mapping from X into Y.

Show that if A and B are subsets of X, then

$(A⊂B)⇒(f(A)⊂f(B))$

but $(f(A)⊂f(B))$  does not imply that $(A⊂B)$

and if A' and B' are subsets of Y, then

$(A′⊂B′)⇒(f^{-1}(A′)⊂f^{−1}(B′))$

Thank you for any help!

edit: they're from Mathematical Analysis by Zorich

edit: sorry for the sloppiness on the initial post.

Comment: Maybe the first formula is wrongly written...

Comment: I don't think so... I'm just really new to relations, set theory, and just proofs in general, which is why I'm having a hard time. I think they're supposed to be pretty basic proofs.

Comment: First one makes no sense.

Comment: or is the first one really false.. plz help with either

Comment: $(f(A)⊂f(B)) \neq (A⊂B)$ makes no sense. Do you mean to say that "$(A\subset B)\implies (f(A)⊂f(B))$ but $(f(A)⊂f(B)) $ does not imply $(A⊂B)$"?

Comment: yea. i think that's what the textbook meant.

Comment: alright i believe it's all edited. thanks everyone for helping me clarify. if there's anything else that's unclear plz let me know

Answer (score 0):

For the first one we have:
$A\subset B$.
Take $x\in f(A) \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x)\subset A \subset B$.

So $x \in f(B)$.

For a counter argument use the function:
$f(0)=0,f(1)=0,f(2)=1$ and
$A={0},B={1,2}$

Then: $f(A)=\{0\}\subset \{0,1\}=f(B)$ but $A=\{0\}\not\subset \{1,2\}=B$

For the second one we have:

$A'\subset B'$

Take $x\in f^{-1}(A') \Rightarrow f(x)\in A' \subset B'$.

So: $x\in f^{-1}(B')$